# I am trying to get a list of unique values from a 2d array and multiple columns using Pandas like an distinct list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe structure and want a list or a single columns containing all unique values from the entire data frame

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | apple | apple | banana |
| banana | pineapple | apple | apple |
| apple | melon | apple | grape |

I already tried so many things that I am lost.
I`ve tried `.unique`and `.drop_duplicates`also

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'\b(\w+)(,+\s+\1)+\b', r'\1')
```

or

```
df.pivot_table(columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3', 'column 4'], aggfunc='size')
```

Comment: Unique values globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> df.stack().unique()
array(['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'melon', 'grape'], dtype=object)
```

`.stack()` makes the dataframe into a single series, i.e. 1-dimensional data, and [`pd.Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) then works as you expect, returning the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Just `stack` the dataframe, drop the duplicates, and call `tolist()` on the resulting series:

```py
>>> df.stack().drop_duplicates().to_list()

['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'melon', 'grape']
```